# Yosemite: Manage NSPopover’s Vibrancy Effect

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsvisualeffectview

With the OS X 10.10 SDK, `NSPopover` seems to default to including an `NSVisualEffectView` somewhere in its hierarchy. Trouble is, I can’t seem to find any way to manage the effect.

I’ve tried the Xcode View Debugger but that didn’t offer very much information:

[image: View Debugger Screenshot]

Are we expected to be able to tweak this vibrancy or just accept it and move on?

I wouldn't mind being able to tweak the effect or change the appearance of certain items in the (apparently enforced) dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to set the NSPopover's `appearance` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSPopover/appearance) to an instance of NSAppearance.

There are a number of [standard appearances](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSAppearance_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Standard_Appearances) including both light and dark vibrancy, along with a `allowsVibrancy` property for custom appearances.

While the documentation for the vibrance appearances says:

> This should only be set on an NSVisualEffectView or one of its subviews.

The NSPopover documentation doesn't appear to have been updated (the comment for `appearance` still references the NSPopoverAppearance enum), so it is probably worth a shot.